# How to resolve issue starting Ruby on Rails server on Cloud9 ide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to start the web server for a rails app on a Cloud9 IDE workspace and I'm receiving this error message:

> `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/server (LoadError)

This is the code that I am running:

```
rails s -p $PORT -b $IP server
```

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails so my apologies if this pretty simple.

Comment: did you run: "bundle install"?

Comment: yes i did.  i actually figured this out... i forgot that the s was short for server and didn't need the "server" on the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running

```
$ rails s -p $PORT -b $IP server
```

when it should just be

```
$ rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
```

You probably added an extraneous `server` because you're used to running `rails server`, but `rails s` is just a shorthand for the former.

It looks like the extra argument to `rails` is causing it to look for a file named `server` in `rack/handler`, and when it doesn't find a file it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what was wrong and its working beautifully now.